# Report based on the send language of an email

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, custom-report-type

i have an email who is sent in different language depending on the country of the contact.

How can i create a report based on the attribute "Langue" or" Country" of my
sendable Data extension ? with numbers of clicks and opens ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce Marketing Cloud won’t be able to generate a report based on Data Extension attribute (languages or Country) OOB. You should enable Send Logs to capture for each send the attribute of the Data Extension containing the preferred language. Use a SQL query to find the right subscribers based on their attributes and tracking activities. The values will be inserted in a Data Extension. The value can be then either exported manually or automated on the FTP server for reporting.

[Send Logging Info](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_send_logging.htm&type=5)

[image: Language - Send Log Solution]

Comment: thank you for the answer.

But when I want to create a send log DE, i can't find the "send log model".

Should I ask the support to activate it ? or there is some other reason that i couldn't find the send log model ?

Comment: Yes, you should create a support case and they should activate this pretty quickly.

Comment: If this answer is helping you, please don't hesitate to classify this question as resolved.

Comment: Nice graphic @JeremyGarcia