# Report by country for multilingual Email

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting

I use one single ampscripted email template for sending out emails to customers in different countries and different languages. Just one Email send for all. I'm now looking for a reporting solution which groups the email performance by country.

What is best practice here?

Thanks and kind regards,
Oliver

Comment: So the country is a column in your list?

Comment: Yes. CountryCodes.

Comment: do you know SQL and have Automation Studio?

Comment: Of course, yes. What is your solution?

Comment: There were some Data Extract Types missing in my account. Include GEO hopefully is the type that helps me here -> https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_extract_types_reference.htm&type=5

Comment: Jeremy's answer will work, it's what I was going to suggest, but you need SQL to do it

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at one of my previous answer on a similar topic. This should help you: [Report based on the send language of an email](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/215889/report-based-on-the-send-language-of-an-email/215992#215992)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's complicated but should work. Any experience with the report "Blank Template for Email Sending Performance". I can drag a country to this report,  but how do I get the correct value?